# Efficient way to iterate through 2 different list in java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 different list

```
List<FooResponse> foos = Arrays.asList(new Foo(1, "Test", "COMPLETE"), new Foo(2, "Test", "IN_PROGRESS"), new Foo(3, "Test", "ERROR"));
List<BarResponse> bars = Arrays.asList(new Bar(11, "Test values"), new Bar(12, "Test values2"), new Bar(13, "Test values 3"));
```

How to iterate through the above lists and take out the first element in both list without any matching parameters and create a list of FooBarMap likebelow?

Result:

```
List<FooBarMap> = Arrays.asList(new FooBar(1, 11), new FooBar(2, 12), new FooBar(3, 13));
```

Answer (score 3):

Streams are a great resource but sometimes a simple imperative solution is the way to go.  If you really want it to be efficient, then use a loop.  Without knowing your classes I have used `getValue()` for retrieval and am using a `List<FooBar>`.  It should be simple to modify this to your exact requirements. This also presumes both lists are the same size.

```
List<FooBar> foobars = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++) {
     foobars.add(new FooBar(foos.get(i).getValue(), bars.get(i).getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a stream of indexes.

```java
var res = IntStream.range(0, foos.size()).mapToObj(i -> 
              new FooBar(foos.get(i).getSomeVal(), bars.get(i).getSomeVal())).toList();
```